Why are Security Issues in Ghostscript not yet fixed in Ubuntu?
Currently there are several known security issues in Ghostscript:

CVE-2024-29510

CVE-2024-29506

CVE-2024-29507

CVE-2024-29508

CVE-2024-29509

CVE-2024-29510, see https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/cve-2024-29510

CVE-2024-29511


not fixed in actual Versions of Ubuntu? gs is part of CUPS and therefore on almost every Ubuntu computer. This is a very attractive security target for malicious people!
See for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion
https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/
https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Cybersicherheitswarnungen/DE/2023/2023-248889-1012.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=2
https://tuxcare.com/blog/ghostscript-vulnerability-actively-exploited-in-attacks/
https://securityaffairs.com/165449/hacking/ghostscript-vulnerability-cve-2024-29510.html

Unfortunately, I don't know much about computer security. But what I have read worries me and I am surprised that the existing version 10.03.1 has not yet been rolled out generally.

Ubuntu software in the repositories rarely gets version rollouts to replace things.  Instead, things are patched in place by individual patches and not a full version release.  It looks to me like these CVEs you've indicated are patched according to the CVE tracker for Ubuntu on security.ubuntu.com.  Go to https://ubuntu.com/security/cves and look at each CVE and you should see "Fixed" for currently supported releases of Ubuntu.

Stop reading those clickbait sites. You have been badly misled by them. Start listening to the Ubuntu Security Podcast to get real, useful advice about how computer security works in general and in Ubuntu.

I offer: the vigilance you show in your question is a good thing, as it contributes to a living culture of security. I would interpret that the downvotes are addressing the circumstance that you had shown a bias towards accusation, while your protocol for vigilance got demonstrated to be missing an important ingredient: familiarity with the platform's infrastructure itself. In any case, your question had facilitated my education: thanks to the dialog in this thread, I also got to understand Ubuntu's patching protocols better.

I think Tuxcare actually offers a serious product. And I agree with Levente, the downvotes are most likely because OP tossed around accusations, without really investigating how Ubuntu handles CVE's - and there are plenty of information about that on the Ubuntu website.

I don't know why you're not fact checking things, but of the posts you've linked and all the CVEs you've listed, these CVEs and issues are already patched in Ubuntu.
In Ubuntu, security fixes tend to be applied as patches to specific versions rather than a full version update.  These "clickbaity" sites you're referring to don't include distro-patching in their circle of assessments.
When presented with a CVE, you need to check in the Ubuntu CVE Tracker and search the CVE in question and then check if the packages are patched.  As Ghostscript is part of CUPS and the Main pocket, it gets security updates from the Security Team.
Last I checked, all the CVEs you've listed are already patched in supported Ubuntu releases.  Therefore, the "issue" is nonexistent as these CVEs are already fixed.
Please don't rely on third party sites to tell you if something is patched or not.  Instead, it is more prudent to do Due Diligence and research whether Ubuntu or your distribution of choice has patches available, which is the case for Ubuntu here.

Thomas (and the other commenters): Thank you for your explanations, especially for the Ubuntu CVE Tracker link. If one enables the detailed view there, one sees in which Ubuntu versions they have been patched. - I was unaware that patching does is not reflected int the version number.

@AdalbertHanßen i'm glad I could help you.  The actual version of the software doesn't change, but the package revision does when a package gets patched.  it's confusing, I know, but the main version string(s) only change when a new upstream version is applied and not when patches are applied because patches are cherry-picked and not full release version updates.
